# SQL query identify sales on both dates

Tags: sql

I need a quick query (SQL) to identify same store sales for the same part before and after a sales promotion.  Ideally create a flag "sssp_ind"(it does not currently exist in the data table) to identify the stores and parts.

A mockup of the client's data provided is presented below.

[image]

Store 1 sold part A in both the pre period and the post period (neon yellow).  Flag trips.
Store 2 sold part F in both the pre and post period (light yellow) and also trips the flag.

No others will trip the flag.
Can't get quite get my head around this one.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that pre_post only contains two values Pre and Post, You can simply use `WINDOW` function as follows:

```
SELECT s.* ,
      CASE WHEN MIN(pre_post) OVER (PARTITION BY STORE, part) <> 
                MAX(pre_post) OVER (PARTITION BY STORE, part) 
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SSNP_ID
FROM SalesData s;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTE ([Common Table Expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)) to get `pre` and `post` data and join it. Here is the sample code:

```
WITH PreSales AS (
    SELECT store, part
    FROM SalesData
    WHERE pre_post = 'pre'
),
PostSales AS (
    SELECT store, part
    FROM SalesData
    WHERE pre_post = 'post'
)
SELECT s.* 
, sssp_ind = CASE WHEN p.store IS NOT NULL AND q.store IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM SalesData s
LEFT JOIN PreSales p ON s.store = p.store AND s.part = p.part
LEFT JOIN PostSales q ON s.store = q.store AND s.part = q.part;
```

Here is sample output:

[image]

Here is [fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/ufayiJuM) to run sample code above

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses

First we identify which parts have both pre and post values :

```
select store, part
from SalesData
group by store, part
having count(case when pre_post = 'pre' then 1 end) = 1
       and count(case when pre_post = 'post' then 1 end) = 1
```

Then, we perform a left join of SalesData with this dataset, marking the matching rows with a flag of 1 :

```
select s.*, case when t.store is not null then 1 else 0 end as sssp_ind
from SalesData s
left join (
  select store, part
  from SalesData
  group by store, part
  having count(case when pre_post = 'pre' then 1 end) = 1
       and count(case when pre_post = 'post' then 1 end) = 1
) as t on s.store = t.store and s.part = t.part;
```

Results :

```
store   part    date        pre_post    nbrsold sssp_ind
1       A       2023-12-01  pre         21      1
1       B       2023-12-01  pre         5       0
1       C       2023-12-01  pre         16      0
2       D       2023-12-01  pre         24      0
2       E       2023-12-01  pre         10      0
2       F       2023-12-01  pre         9       1
1       BB      2023-12-08  post        14      0
1       A       2023-12-08  post        6       1
1       F       2023-12-08  post        9       0
2       A       2023-12-08  post        12      0
2       F       2023-12-08  post        35      1
2       Z       2023-12-08  post        19      0
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/w8TjMOWf)